# inserting images to div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I like add text and some images to a div using jquery.

I can do this to add text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 

$("#help").text('This is the description').css({"border": "1px solid", "color": "Black", "font-size": "14px", "font-weight": "bold", "padding": "30px 0 30px 0", "width": "auto", "height": "auto", "text-align": "left", "background": "lightyellow"});
```

I tried this:

```
$("#help").append('<img src="description.png" alt="box_plot_description" />'); 

});
```

How would append image to this text using jquery?

I have added the append after text but, append is overwriting the div. I like have text at the beginning of the div and after that an image.

Comment: see @Shyju's answer. You need to use .html() instead of .text()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `html()` method

```
$("#help").html('<img src="somesrc.jpg" alt="someimage" />');
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/HdFqr/3/

If you want to keep the existing content and append the image, use `append` method

```
$("#help").text("Some Text");
$("#help").append('<img src="somesrc.jpg" alt="someimage" />');
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/HdFqr/4/

You can also use [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method as well

```
var img=$("<img />").attr("src","someimag.jpg");
img.appendTo($("#help"));
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/HdFqr/6/

Comment: Thank you for your response. This overwrites my div, I like to append to my div. Basically, I look to put some description in text and then add an image.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append:

```
$('#divid').append('<img src="path" />');
```

If you just want to set a specific image:

```
$('#divid').html('<img src="path" />');
```

Comment: Everlof, I have update the code. When I do append after text, it overrites my div. I dont see the text in the div anymore.

Comment: Well, it depends how do you want it to look? This example uses p tags for the text http://jsfiddle.net/HdFqr/10/

Answer (score 1):

You can insert an image with `.html()`

```
$("#help").html('<img src="description.png" alt="box_plot_description" />');
```